# What happens when you await an asynchronous task in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

From what I understood in all async/await tutorials in C#, I get that when we define an async method, it means that we can add the await keyword inside it with a task as a parameter, to make the method return to caller if the task is too long. The method can then resume when task is completed.

```
public void MyMainMethod()
{
   DoSomethingAsync();
   KeepOnDoingOtherStuff();
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   //Do whatever
   await LongOperation();
   // Rest of the method that is executed when the long operation is 
    //finished.

}
```

So here while the long operation is going on, as it is awaited, the DoSomething async gives hand to the MainMethod and the KeepOnDoingOtherStuff is executed. OK

Now my problem is if my DoSomethingAsync itself is awaited. In this case:

```
public async void MyMainMethod()
{
   await DoSomethingAsync();

   //Here is a critical method that I want to execute only when 
     //DoSomethingAsync is finished

   CriticalStuff();
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   //Do whatever
   await LongOperation();
   // Rest of the method that is executed when the long operation is 
    //finished.

}
```

Now I await my DoSomethingAsync so that I am sure that it doesn't go further, but the problem is that the DoSomethingAsync () still gives hand to the caller when it awaits the LongOperation(), and my Main method resumes, which I don't want because it executes my critical thing.

There is something I quite miss in asynchronous logic, what then would be the point to "await" a method that has asynchronous methods inside it?

I would very much appreciate a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your second example, `CriticalStuff()` should not be called until `DoSomethingAsync()` is completely finished. There must be something missing in the example code you posted here.

Comment: This is a good article about Asynchronous Programming in case you are interested in reading more about this topic. https://rubikscode.net/2018/05/28/asynchronous-programming-in-net-common-mistakes-and-best-practices/

Comment: Your MyMainMethod() should return a Task and whatever that's calling that should await

Comment: _"the problem is that the DoSomethingAsync () still gives hand to the caller when it awaits the LongOperation(), and my **Main method resumes**"_ It shouldn't... the `await` within it should see to that, the same as the `await` on `LongOperation`.  As @Stijn says, if this is happening, there must be something else going on in your code you're not showing.

Comment: *only when DoSomethingAsync is finished* in the code you've posted that is exactly what will happen. Is it not? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: @JamesThorpe  Your comment points out something I might be missing. If I await a task1 that itself is async and has in it an await Task2 in it, when exactly does the code considers task1 as finished and keeps on going? Because it seems that as soon as I hit await task2, it goes back to the caller and the code in the caller after "await task1" is executed..

Answer (score 7):

I think the mismatch here comes from these words:

> to make the method return to caller if the task is too long.

`await` isn't about *long*, exactly. It is about *asynchronous*. If something takes a long time but happens on local CPU then sure: it isn't really a great fit for `await` (although you *can* use the `await` machinery as a convenient way of pushing things to a worker thread, and then rejoin a sync-context thread when it completes).

The better example, though, is when the task is *external*; it could be a call to a SQL database, or to redis, or via http, or to another process over some kind of IO layer, or waiting for socket data. Note that even talking to physically local SSD storage can involve long waits, at least as measured by CPU speeds. When the local thread would be doing *nothing except blocking* (waiting for a reply), then : in many cases there are much better things that the thread could be doing.

In the case of a client app, those "better things" include painting the UI and responding to input. In the case of a server app, those "better things" include servicing other concurrent requests / load.

---

When measured in this way: `await` acts as an effective way of writing code that needs data from external sources, but doesn't want to just *block* the current thread while that data arrives. If that isn't your scenario: `await` might not be for you.

Comment: I get it. but for me the point for DoSomethingAsync to be async is that it can go back to a caller while it's doing its long operation. However, the "caller" is awaiting the DoSomethingAsync Task, so it won't do anything while it is not complete. Hence I could make the DoSomethingAsync synchronous. In other words, why would any Task we await be async ?

Comment: @Zeppelin you're talking about concurrency, while I'm talking about asynchronicity - related but different. I'm mostly focusing on asynchronicity, in which case the key thing you're overlooking is that **threads are expensive**, and that in many scenarios, there are *unrelated* things that your thread could be usefully doing, rather than blocking. In terms of what you're saying about concurrency: sure, there are scenarios where you can usefully use `async` to coordinate 2 (or more) activities, and : that's perfectly valid. Just... don't `await` until your ready to "join" (in threading terms)

Comment: @Zeppelin to put that into context: one of the things I run is a web-socket server that services about 60k TCP connections per instance. There's no way I can run 60k threads (well, 120k threads - read+write per socket); the historic async IO APIs are ... very hard to get right; doable, but *really really hard*. But: to get the same result with `async`/`await`: trivial to do - really nice simple code. There's nothing that `await` adds that you couldn't already do with uglier, harder, buggier code. But `await` makes it *easy to get it right*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm discussing this variant of your code:

```
public async void MyMainMethod()
{
   await DoSomethingAsync();

   //Here is a critical method that I want to execute only when 
     //DoSomethingAsync is finished

   CriticalStuff();
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   //Do whatever
   await LongOperation();
   // Rest of the method that is executed when the long operation is 
    //finished.

}
```

When `DoSomethingAsync` returns, it doesn't just blindly hand control back to the calling method. It hands it a `Task`. If the method in fact completed synchronously, it'll hand back a task that's already completed. Otherwise, if the method still has work to do, the `Task` will be running, not (yet) completed.

So, `DoSomethingAsync` actually triggers some async behaviour and returns back a not-yet-completed `Task` to `Main`. What does `Main` do with it? It `await`s it. `await` is how that method indicates "I can't do anything useful unless this awaitable (usually a `Task`) is complete".

If (as here), the `Task` isn't yet completed, it doesn't make any further progress (itself) until that happens. If this is the first (required) `await` in the method, it's at this point that the async machinery kicks in, signs up a continuation and returns from `Main` itself.

It won't step past any `await` line until the `Task` (or other awaitable) that you provide as the `await` argument is complete, and for methods using the `async` machinery, that's not until that method is completely done.

(I've ignored the exception story in the above description. It's all happy path stuff)

Comment: So when you say the Main "can't do anything useful until the DoSomethingAsync is finished" : when can we say that is officially finished? because in this task there is another task running and being awaited  ( await LongOperation() ) .IF I apply the logic: in DoSomethingAsync I hit the LongOperation() that is awaited -> it is not completed yet so we go back to the caller --> which is is Main and what is after await DoSomethingAsync() ....(which is what i specifically don't want as nothing is finished yet..).   This is where my confusion is coming from...

Comment: @Zeppelin - I'll try phrasing it another way - whenever you hit an `await` and actually have to wait, the `Task` that represents completion of *this method call* is still marked as Running, not Complete. Your method isn't considered complete until that `Task` transitions to `Complete`. And it's that `Task` that your caller can in turn `await` on. Any clearer?

Comment: So in the example case: while the LongOperation() Task has not transitioned to Complete, my DoSomethingAsync will not be able to transition to complete, am I right?

Comment: Correct. With this sort of code, it's not unusual to find that you've got several `Task`s, each one representing the pending activity for each async method in the call stack.

Comment: So what would be the point of making the DoSomethingAsync    async? I could call synchronously the LongOperation(), it wouldn't change anything would it? As the caller can't keep on while my LongOperation is not complete. I don't see the point of having a Task being awaited inside a Task being awaited itself.

Comment: @Zeppelin - if the `await` is the final statement in the method and is the only `await` present in that method, there's little point in making that method `async`. However, you indicated that `DoSomethingAsync` had `// Rest of the method that is executed when the long operation is finished.` `LongOperation` may be finished but that doesn't imply that `DoSomethingAsync` is - that's why each has its own `Task`.

Comment: @Zeppelin - if you've got the time, I'd suggest you read Eric Lippert's [Continuation Passing Style, Revisited](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one/) series (link to part one). It may seem it's got nothing to do with this at first but if you make it through to the end, you may be able to see some of these details better.

Comment: I agree, but for me the point for DoSomethingAsync to be async is that it can go back to a caller while it's doing its long operation. However, the "caller" is awaiting the DoSomethingAsync Task, so it won't do anything while it is not complete. Hence I could make  the DoSomethingAsync  synchronous, it wouldn't change anything ..  Thanks for the link!